# Why is the player falling through the platform(rectangular layer)?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I am implementing a 2D platformer game.The player is Box2d which is falling through the platform.I dont understand why is it happening?I have created rectangular layers for the platforms in Tiled Map editor. Here is the code for create player and createBlocks and getrectangle method

Comment: There's a ton of stuff here and I'm not familiar with the libraries, but I notice that you're using integer values (`/ 2`) in a lot of places, which might cause problems, and I don't know whether you're using `==` comparisons anywhere, but those don't play nicely with floating-point.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I can think of to debug this would be:

1. Remove all the bit masking and filtering.
2. Check all values are floats and not accidentally rounding to zero for example.
3. Try making 1 static block and one dynamic one with gravity and just test it separately from the rest of the code.

Check if the issue is solved between each step but if all else fails, I would rewrite the whole lot...

Comment: by removing the bit masking and filtering, how will i know the collision wd be working or not?It doesnot make sense to remove the bit filtering...

Comment: If it starts colliding, your bit filtering is messed up.